# Event emitter stencil undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, stenciljs

Im building a web component with stencil based on react.
The value is emited but its showing undefined on the component when im calling.

```js
  @Event() newModuleClicked: EventEmitter<any>;

  handleClick(e) {
    this.newModuleClicked.emit(e); //data is coming here when clicked
  }



   <ul class="portal-navigation__scrollable">
            {this.dataNavigation.map((item) => (
              <li key={item.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(item.Name)}>
               {item.Name}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
```

The component im calling its showing undefined

```html
  <navigation
    [dataNavigation]="data"
    (newModuleClicked)="onChange($event)"
  ></navigation>
```

```js
  onChange(ev: any) {
    console.log('got data', ev.target.value); //undefined 
  }
```

Comment: As it's a Custom Event, you should log ev.detail, not ev.target.value
https://stenciljs.com/docs/events
Have you tried this ?

Comment: onChangeArea(ev: any) {
    console.log (ev['detail']);
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value you pass to `.emit()` will be in the `detail` property of the `CustomEvent` the Stencil component emits. So to get the actual name just rewrite your event handler to:

```
onChange(ev: any) {
    console.log('got data', ev.detail);
}
```

You can also give the event a more specific type of [`CustomEvent<any>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent) (the `any` being derived from the event declaration of `EventEmitter<any>`):

```
onChange(ev: CustomEvent<any>) {
    console.log('got data', ev.detail);
}
```

Comment: CustomEvent cant be used since the function is Event emitter in first function. but only  ev.detail is working. Thank you

Comment: The EventEmitter emits CustomEvents so that's the correct type [as shown in the docs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/events#listen-decorator).